# Second Order ODE De-coupling

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have two coupled second order DE that can be written as

$$\begin{pmatrix}
\ddot y_1  \\
\ddot y_2  \\
\end{pmatrix}  =
\begin{pmatrix}
-10 & 4  \\
4 & -4  \\
\end{pmatrix}
 \begin{pmatrix}
 y_1  \\
 y_2  \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

I need to find the solutions. I have tried to find the eigenvalues and I find that they are -12 and -2. But then I am not sure how to write the solution.

The eigenvectors are for -12
$$\begin{pmatrix}
 2  \\
 -1  \\
\end{pmatrix}$$
and for 
-2
$$ \begin{pmatrix}
 1  \\
 2  \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

I cannot form a solution after this. Simple I dont know how to proceed. Can anyone help me please..

Comment: I think you should introduce two new functions: $$\dot{y_1}=y_3 \\ \dot{y_2}=y_4 $$ then you get a system of four 1st order linear ODEs

Answer (score 3):

Per my comment, we get a linear 1st order system:

$$\begin{bmatrix} \dot{y_1} \\  \dot{y_2} \\  \dot{y_3} \\  \dot{y_4} \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\  0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\  -10 & 4 & 0 & 0 \\ 4 & -4 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} y_1 \\  y_2 \\  y_3 \\  y_4 \end{bmatrix} $$

With eigenvalues:

$$\lambda_{1,2}=\pm i\sqrt{2} \\ \lambda_{3,4}=\pm 2i\sqrt{3}$$

For eigenvectors you can look at [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B0+,+0+,+1+,+0+%7D,%7B+0+,+0+,+0+,+1+%7D,%7B+-10+,+4+,+0+,+0+%7D,%7B+4+,+-4+,+0+,+0+%7D%7D) output.

Comment: But is it easier to solve like this..?

Comment: @ArthurMorgan, a matter of preference.

Answer (score 3):

Your system can be written in factored matrix/vector form,

$$\ddot Y=T\Lambda T^{-1}Y,$$

or

$$T^{-1}\ddot Y=\Lambda T^{-1}Y,$$ which is of the form

$$\ddot Z=\Lambda Z.$$

Hence the solutions in $Z$ will be linear combinations of $e^{\pm i\sqrt2x}$ and $e^{\pm i\sqrt{12}x}$, and so will the solutions in $Y$.

Comment: Is the answer is $y_1=2c_1cos(\sqrt{12}t)+c_2cos(\sqrt{2}t)$

Comment: @ArthurMorgan: no, there are more terms.

Comment: 1/5 in front of the equation ?

Comment: @ArthurMorgan: I said more terms. This is a standard non-damped oscillator.

Answer (score 2):

With the (left) eigenvectors you now know which linear combinations to choose that decouple the system, $u_1=2y_1-y_2$ and $u_2=y_1+2y_2$. Then 
$$
\ddot u_1=2\ddot y_1-\ddot y_2=-12(2y_1-y_2)=-12u_1
$$
and
$$
\ddot u_2=\ddot y_1+2\ddot y_2=-2(y_1+2y_2)=-2u_2
$$
These are both harmonic oscillators and the solutions thereof recombine to solutions of the original system as $y_1=\frac15(2u_1+u_2)$, $y_2=\frac15(2u_2-u_1)$.

Comment: I am not sure I understand it. What is $u$ then..? I mean you defined $y_1$ in terms of $u$, okay but then its missing for me

Comment: The $u_j$ are linear combinations of the $y_i$, as written in the first sentence. The coefficients are the components of the left eigenvectors. Because the matrix is symmetric, these are the same as the right eigenvectors. In principle this is a more elementary execution of the method in the answer of Yves Daoust.

Comment: when I put the $u_1=(2y_1-y_2)$ and $u_2$ on the $y_1$ equation I get $y_1=y_1$ ?

Comment: Wait. I understand it so sorry. I ll solve the u and then put it in y okay